# How do I turn off battery warning in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery, notification

My battery is broken, so it's always at 0%. How can I remove the annoying notify-send with beep warning about low battery?

Things I've tried so far:

- Altering `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`
- **dconf-editor → org → gnome → settings-daemon → plugins → power** (which  seems to save settings to file `UPower.conf`)
- `service upower stop`
- `service acpid stop`
- Various GUI power related options in **System Settings**

Nothing seems to stop the damn popup.

Comment: What about removing the battery? If it's dead already...

Comment: @CelticWarrior Can't remove the battery on this laptop.

M.Becerra I'll check the link and get back to you about it, thanks!

Comment: doesn't look like a duplicate to me - MetalGodwin please update when possible